# Help with voltage regulator

Tags: usb, voltage-regulator, cables

I’m very confused on how a voltage regulator is used. On this one that I found: [Fasizi 3.3 DC Voltage Regulator 4.75V-12V to 3.3V 800mA](https://www.amazon.se/dp/B09Z28LTRD?ref_=cm_sw_r_apin_dp_2TVTY9WMTCYR0JPT0H23&language=en_GB), I have no clue where which cables should go where. If I use a USB cable, where do the data+ and data- wires go? There are only 3 pins on it. Or do I only connect the power and ground to the regulator?

Is it also possible to use this one: [LM317T](https://www.kopplat.se/Produkt/9202/LM317T_spanningsregulator_12_-_37_V_15_A_TO220?gad=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwjMiiBhA4EiwAZe6jQ6SmufRXZx28YtTMml_242AQ5LnlxB1h9p7jV-jeOufzIElg_Tp3VRoCEVIQAvD_BwE), without a PCB or whatever they’re called and just connect the cables?

Comment: Very closely related to previous question, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/665225/laptop-webcam-cabling.

Comment: You're assuming that you can connect that webcam to a regular external USB 2 hub/host just by regulating the supply voltage down. That's not necessarily the case, although here it looks like you may be lucky.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Well, playing with things you don't have the manuals for is always a bit of a guessing  game.

Comment: @Johannes We assume (estimate, guess) the data wires are just normal USB (which does not use full voltage) and the voltage only needs to be changed for the power wire.

Comment: ... probably a good idea to mention that guessing *wrong* has a risk of damaging the camera. That's why you try to measure things as much as possible, but in the end, you don't have the documents so there is always a chance that there was something you didn't know about. Still, lots of people do this kind of guesswork all the time and mostly make things work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage regulator regulates the supply voltage. As long as the webcam still uses the standard 3.3V USB signalling, the data wires connect directly, bypassing the voltage regulator.

The three pins on your first regulator are VIN, OUT, and GND; assuming this manufacturer has named these pins in the typical way, they would be wired as follows:

- The ground of the USB supply, webcam, and regulator GND are all connected together
- VIN connects to the +5V from the USB supply
- OUT connects to the +3.3V line on the load.

However, there are some fishy specs with this regulator. It doesn't seem to have a consistent current rating, among other things. Prefer a trustworthy device or module with a clear datasheet if possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you have any suggestions on a trustworthy voltage regulator?

Comment: @Johannes I'm not sure what's available in your region. If I were shipping to the US, I'd buy https://www.adafruit.com/product/2745 since I trust that vendor. Chances are the regulator you linked should be fine or will fail in a safe way (overheat and shut down); I just can't confirm its specs. A webcam shouldn't need that much current though.

Comment: ok! but how do I know what current the webcam needs?

Comment: @Johannes You'll have to either measure. find a spec sheet, or extrapolate from similar webcams that do have a spec sheet

Comment: @Johannesyou here's a *guess* for you: less than 200mA. (Which means that a regulator designed for 800mA will work. You don't have to use the whole 800mA)